# How can I simulate online data arrival in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I need to simulate a sensor sending data in order to test my algorithm. How can I do this in MATLAB? For example, say I create a noisy sine wave like this:

```
t = [0:1:1000];
vn = .2;
f = .5;
fs = 50;
x = 4*sin(2*pi*f/fs*t) + vn*rand(size(t));
```

x is simulation data only, where f is the frequency of the signal and fs is the sampling frequency. I would like to get one element of x every .02 seconds, or 50 Hz, into a function I have defined. So, when my function starts I would get x(1), then at 0.02 seconds later I would get x(2) and so on...

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a [timer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/use-a-matlab-timer-object.html) object:

```
x = 11:20; % some test data
myFunction = @(i) disp(x(i)); % test function that just displays x(i)
i = 1;

% configure the timer
t = timer;
t.TimerFcn = 'myFunction(i); i = i + 1;'
t.StopFcn = @(timerObj, ~) delete(timerObj) % required according to manual
t.Period = 0.5; %change this later to 0.02
t.ExecutionMode = 'fixedRate';
t.TasksToExecute = length(x);

start(t) % start the timer
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be really accurate you can pause your execution for the needed time. For example:

```
for i=1:1:length(x)
 .....
 pause(0.02)
end
```

This will work assuming the time taken to process your time is dismissful. If it is not you may want to consider tic-toc to get t- the time taken for processing and then pause for 0.02-t.

Comment: But won't this pause also affect the function I'm calling?

Comment: You can measure the time taken for the function to process and then pause for the rest of the time. The pause will be after the function you are calling. Unless it takes more then 0.02 sec to run your function